# Strings are not erased from memory after calling FreeLibrary

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to create a DLL for a project, and I'm having some issues clearing up the strings. 
I have a class where I have a couple of strings declared on the stack like this:

```
std::string test = "blabla";
```

Whenever I use FreeLibrary to eject the DLL from the process, the strings remain in memory, even though the DLL is no longer in the process.

I am deleting the class itself before calling FreeLibrary, and its constructor is definitely called.

I have tried a couple of programs like Process Hacker and Cheat Engine, and both return the correct string when searching for it through memory.

It's weird that it's not deleting itself, since the string is allocated on the stack.

Is there a certain function that I need to use?

Comment: This can be implementation defined and relies on the OS memory manager. From a code standpoint, what happens after a `free` or a exit from a scope where a container is declared isn't guaranteed. What is guaranteed is that you can no longer validly access that information. In most cases the memory is simply released for reuse, not zeroed in any way. Also note that `"blabla"` is a string literal and will be part of the program throughout, regardless of any library load or release.

Comment: So there is no actual way to remove the text from memory?

Comment: You can never remove `"blabla"` that is a *string literal constant* most likely created in the read-only section of the executable. As far as`test` goes, the best you can do is iterate over `test` (e.g. `for (auto& c : test)` and set each character to some random or fixed value before calling `test.clear()`. It's out of your hands at that point.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @selbie I am trying to eject my DLL without leaving any traces in the main executable.

Answer (score 0):

I want to preface my answer by saying that unless you are making some sort of cryptographic library where sensitive information is involved, *there really isn't a good reason for doing this.* And in fact if you *are* doing that you should take additional steps to obfuscate the code so it isn't clear what it's doing. But I'll show you a simple way to do this.

> It's weird that it's not deleting itself, since the string is allocated on the stack.

That is normal. There really isn't anything special about the stack, except that it's generally quicker and less costly to access compared to the heap and runs in an opposite direction.

When your program is loaded into memory it gets loaded with a `.bss` and a `.data` section. String literals are in the `.data` section which is read-only memory.  If you want to ensure that something cannot be seen in memory, you *must not* use a string literal. `"blabla"` in quotation marks is a string literal.

**This is how to avoid using a string literal:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test = { 'b','l','a','b','l','a','\0' };
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    // Okay, I'm done with it now...
    test.assign(6,'\0'); // blabla is replaced with zeroes
}
```